# CB Joomla Redirect each user to page after login?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Hi there is there a free CB extension or hack that would help me out with redirecting the user after login to a specified page the administrator setups for the user. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Components, Community Builder, Configuration.

On the registration tab, you can set the URL of redirection for first time logins.

Otherwise there is a third-party component:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/community-builder-extensions/community-builder-management/11372

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the CB Login module there are 2 options: **Login Redirection URL** and **Logout Redirection URL**.